# Is there way to make pagination pretty url in Laravel 5.4

Tags: laravel, url, pagination

Is there a way to get a pagination pretty URL like this
(http://localhost:8000/users/all/1).

http://localhost:8000/users/all?page=1 this is how it give me as default

Thanks.

Comment: Have you considered this format? http://localhost:8000/users/page/1

Comment: No I need it as localhost:8000/users/1  without page word